# Link application to static version of Qt on Mac

Tags: qt

I am trying to deploy a Qt application by linking it to a static version of Qt.

I followed this [guide](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/deployment-mac.html#static-linking). I have downloaded Qt and compiled it statically. The problem is when I try to link my application to the static version of Qt.

After the application is compiled and linked I check what other libraries the application is linked to:

```
otool -L QtIntro.app/Contents/MacOs/plugandpaint

//output from command:

QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.3)
QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.3)
QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/QtNetwork (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.3)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
/usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1094.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
```

Why is my application still linked to dynamic version of Qt and how can I fix it?

Comment: you are supposed to pay $ for this, you already know that, right ?

Comment: absolutely not, open source means open-source, nothing more, nothing less, read the Qt license before breaking it. You are supposed to link dynamically if you want to use Qt for free, if you want static compilation you have to buy the commercial license and when you buy the license you also receive instructions about how to do this. In the history of software opensource was never equal to "free", be sure you read and understand the license of any piece of software you are using.

Comment: user1849534: well, he can link statically, if his license is compatible (free). That said, it's quite common (much more than static linking) to bundle the dylibs with the app bundle, which makes the application self-contained as well, albeit the download will be larger.

Comment: It's more of an learning experience and i'm not planning on releasing it to the public. I just wanna get my application on a couple of computers so I can try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 99% the case, this is because you still have the dynamic libraries in that particular path. As stated in the documentation:

> The linker will always choose dynamic over static.

Try to move the `*.framework` subdirectories somewhere and kick a clean build again.

Comment: The application wont compile at all if I move the frameworks. Do I need to specify the search path to the static version of Qt in the project or something?

Comment: Won't compile or won't link? If it's the latter, it means the static library wasn't correctly detected. In any case, try explicit linking, e.g. changing `-lQtGui` in the Makefile to `/path/to/your/libQtGui.a'.

Comment: Can't find -lQtGui in my makefile

Comment: Did you search everywhere? Often qmake produces a Makefile.foobar for the final foobar executable. It will contain something like: LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)  --framework ApplicationServices -framew     ork CoreFoundation -framework Security -framework Carbon -framework AppKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreServices -lQtGui -lQtNetwork -lQtCore -lz -lm